# Angular 7 How to get the body (json) of http error in observable

Tags: angular

I'm getting the http header message instead of body of the error (it should be in json)

Please check the following code

```
  this._itemService.createItem(itemData)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    )
```

When I checked it in postman or even in the network in browser dev tool, the response shows correctly as follows (CORS is enabled and works without any issue)

`{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"sku":["The sku field is required."],"price":["The price must be a number."]}}`

when I try to access the error it dont work as a usual json response and I get following in the console for console.log(err.message); ** please check the code above

`Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/item: 422 Unprocessable Entity`

However the expected result should be `"The given data was invalid."` for console.log(err.message)

why is this happen and how I can access the exact json instead of this header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any error returned on the Observable response stream will be wrapped in an `HttpErrorResponse` to provide additional context about the state of the HTTP layer when the error occurred.

> The **error** property will contain either a wrapped Error object or
> the error response returned from the server.

```js
this._itemService.createItem(itemData)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res)
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err.error.message);
    }
  )
```

[HttpErrorResponse @ angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse)

Comment: This answer saved my life. Thank you! Although I'm using angular 11 - err.message worked for me instead of err.error.message

Answer (score 1):

Change your error code to:

```
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                console.log(err.error.message);
              } else {
                console.log(err.message);
              }
            });
```